# What is the best method for getting vendor files on the server?

Tags: 8, installation, composer

I'm fairly new to Drupal 8 development, and I've been a little frustrated with the complications that Composer has added. Nonetheless, I'm trying to determine the best way to get the necessary **/vendor** files on the server.

I understand that Composer recommends that you ignore the **/vendor** directory. However, if you don't have a build server in place, what's the best method to getting the **/vendor** files on the server? Is it common practice to load and run Composer on the server, or is that a big no-no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options.

1. Commit the entire project with Git.
2. Use [Acquia BLT](https://github.com/acquia/blt).

The first method is not preferred because it makes the repository size massive and unwieldy, but if you have no build server you have no build server. But not having a build server isn't necessarily the end, because...

The second choice would allow you to *build locally and deploy to remote* using a [command BLT provides](http://blt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme/deploy/).

Here is an example. I want to build my develop branch and put it on the server. I can enter the repository url in my project.yml file (provided by BLT), and run this command:

```
blt deploy -Ddeploy.branch=develop-build -Ddeploy.commitMsg='PROJECT-000: Generating new build for PROJECT.'
```

This will generate a build artifact (which is *not committed* into your canonical repository), but instead committed to the remote repository being deployed to as `develop-build` or whatever you name the branch. You then switch your dev environment to run that branch instead of `develop`. For instance, my canonical repo lives on GitHub, my remote repo is on Acquia. GitHub won't ever have the `-build` branches committed to it, and the Acquia repo won't ever have `develop` or `master` - it will have the build artifacts of deployed branches. You could use the same repository for both, but its a drag IMO because you (or I, anyway) want the canonical repo to be clean and not be dragging around artifacts of this size.

It *is* easier with a CI server to automate all of this, but Acquia BLT is a viable option when you don't have a CI service to use because you can run the commands yourself from your machine.

Another option would be to build your own scripts to do this as well, but I'd say you are better off starting with BLT. It can be added to existing projects, and it is straight-forward to configure via project.yml.

So no, you do not need to run Composer on the production server. Most hosting companies would never allow this anyway.

Comment: Well, using Acquia BLT is just one of many possible build systems that can be used, having a server to do that is optional. The basic steps is creating a package, putting that on the server, extracting it and switching to that. We mostly use platform.sh, where this is part of the deploy process, but you can build it yourself using tooks like fabric or many others

Comment: Haven’t heard of that, but I assume the process is similar (except the platform sh part)